# Auto release pool, Objective-c with C++ using it properly with multiple languages

Tags: objective-c

I am learning how to use Objective-c which I have never used before with C++ and C. I am realizing that Objective-c really likes you to release objects. This is a .mm C++ based application, more C++ will be used than Objective-c.

In this example should I simply just call `CFRelease(object)` after it's used in the screenshot function. Or is it good practice to use `@autoreleasepool` within your functions.

I was not sure if `@autoreleasepool` releases everything regarding objects that require `CFRelease`.

```
bool screenshot() {
    CGImageRef _Image;
    CFStringRef _Filename, _Format;
    CFURLRef _URLRef;
    CGImageDestinationRef _Destination;

    _Image =  CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectInfinite, (1 << 0), (0), (1 << 0));
    _Filename = CFStringRef(@"screenshot.jpg");
    _Format = CFStringRef(@"public.jpeg");
    _URLRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, _Filename, CFURLPathStyle(0), 0);
    _Destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(_URLRef, _Format, 1, nullptr);

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(_Destination, _Image, nullptr);
    // Use it here?
    @autoreleasepool {
        if ( CGImageDestinationFinalize(_Destination) ) {
            CFRelease(_Destination); // Or individually release
            CFRelease(_URLRef); // Or individually release
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    // Here only, possibly?
    @autoreleasepool {
        screenshot();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ObjC code will need a wrapping @autoreleasepool at some level.  So, it's a good idea to have it in main() at the very least.

The rest of your stuff is more strictly CFFoundation, which is C and not (necessarily) Objective-C.  You will need to call CFRelease on the two you have, as well as _Image, and you should not need an extra autorelease pool around them, as once the retain count goes to zero on CFRelease the memory will be deallocated directly.  If you use CFAutorelease() instead, then you do need the pool, and the objects will live until the nearest wrapping autoreleasepool goes out of scope, at which point it will call CFRelease() (or the -release ObjC method) on all objects in the pool.

So an autorelease is a sort of delayed release, when you still want to use the object in the local scope afterwards.  It's often used for returned values.  If you are using pure CFFoundation and call CFRelease(), then there may not be anything actually autoreleased so there won't be anything in the pool.

You should be using CFRelease() (or CFAutorelease) on the three created objects regardless if the routine returns true or false -- you are done with them.

If you are using regular ObjC, they will likely autorelease objects somewhere below.  You can use autoreleasepools if there is likely a large amount of memory or number of autoreleased objects you want to clean up, possibly before moving to other tasks.  Or sometimes it's done once per loop.

BTW, you can use CFSTR("public.jpg") to get constant CFStringRefs, rather than converting them from constant ObjC NSStrings, but it probably works fine either way.